# Select from dropdown in Meteor when only one value exists

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to select one value from a dropdown in meteor.

It should still be selectable even if it is the only one, as I have a click event based on it. i.e.

```
'click option[data-action="doSomething"]': function(event, template){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Pressed');
    //Do something here.
  }
```

and the HTML looks like:

```
{{#each something}}
<option data-action="doSomething" {{setSelected}}>{{nickname}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

When I try select, this all works but **only when there is more than 1 value to select from.**

Does anyone know how to select when only 1 value exists? Using `click option`.

Comment: can you add a value that results in `<option disabled >Please select</option>` to your `something` array? This will cause your select to always have 2 options unless there is nothing to select.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at the end?

Comment: @HMR that's what we ended up going with for now.

Answer (score 4):

The "click" event won't work for you consistently on `<option>` elements. Use the "change" event on the `<select>` element itself instead. Then you can access the `<option>` element's value from the event handler and apply logic from there.

#### Events

```
'change .actionSelect': function(event, template){
  const selectElem = event.currentTarget;

  switch(selectElem.value)
  {
    case 'action1': 
      // Do a thing
      break;
    case 'action2': 
      // Do a different thing
      break;
  }
}
```

#### Template

```
<select class="actionSelect">
  {{#each thing in something}}
    <option value="{{thing.action}}" selected="{{thing.setSelected}}">{{thing.nickname}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

*Note: I used the "each...in" loop here as it is a best practice. Keeps template-level variables from becoming inaccessible within loops.*

As HMR mentioned in the comments, you might also want to add a default `<option disabled>` element so that you can ensure that the user is prompted to select something "new" when there is only one option.